# Java non-heap keeps increasing in Kubernetes POD

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, openjdk-11

I am using OpenJDK 11 to run a Spring Boot application. I have set the Xmx as 1G and min/max metaspace as 256M. I am runing this inside a kubernetes pod with memory limit as 2G. When the traffic to the pod increases I see OOMKill of pod and the pods restart. I dont see any OOM error in the logs. I enabled native tracking and below is the details of it. Is there some limit which I can apply to fix/tune the same. Will Increasing the MaxMetaspace help

|  | Reserved(MB) | committed(MB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total Allocated | 2026.576 | 1765.548 |
|  |  |  |
| Java Heap | 1048.576 | 1048.576 |
| Class | 325.439 | 222.783 |
| Thread | 54.452 | 20.568 |
| Code | 258.915 | 134.427 |
| GC | 93.113 | 93.113 |
| Compiler | 1.814 | 1.814 |
| Internal | 6.045 | 6.045 |
| Other | 166.385 | 166.385 |
| Symbol | 35.661 | 35.661 |
| Native Memory Tracking | 15.311 | 15.311 |
| Shared class space | 17.012 | 17.012 |
| Arena Chunk | 0.179 | 0.179 |

Comment: Did you figure this out @Amol?